# Calculate the product total sum of each category in Map - Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, sum

I have a Map and I am trying to calculate the total sum value of products for each CategoryName, then get the category where the total sum is the greatest, and display this sum.

I grouped the Map by categories, now i am struggling how i could calculate this sum, any solutions?

That's my class:

```
public class ProductCategories {
        private String categoryName;
        private int productId;
        private double price;

        public ProductCategories(String categoryName, int productId, double price) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
            this.productId = productId;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getCategoryName() {
            return categoryName;
        }

        public int getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }



        public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }

        public void setProductId(int productId) {
            this.productId = productId;
        }

        public void setProductId(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ProductCategories{" + "Category name='" + categoryName + '\'' + ", productID=" + productId + ", price='" + price + '\'' + '}';
        }


        private static Map<String, Integer> productIdToNameMap(List<ProductCategories> categoryList) {
            return categoryList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductCategories::getCategoryName, ProductCategories::getProductId, (first, second) -> first + second, TreeMap::new
                    ));
        }

        private static Map<String, List<ProductCategories>> multiValueMap(List<ProductCategories> categoryList) {
            return categoryList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductCategories::getCategoryName));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<ProductCategories> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            categoryList.add(new ProductCategories("The Fellowship of the Ring", 1954, 12));
            categoryList.add(new ProductCategories("The Return of the King", 1954, 12));
            categoryList.add(new ProductCategories("The Return of the King", 1955, 12));


            //System.out.println(productIdToNameMap(categoryList));
            System.out.println(multiValueMap(categoryList));
        }
}
```

Output:

```
{The Return of the King=[ProductCategories{Category name='The Return of the King', productID=1954, price='12.0'}, ProductCategories{Category name='The Return of the King', productID=1955, price='12.0'}], The Fellowship of the Ring=[ProductCategories{Category name='The Fellowship of the Ring', productID=1954, price='12.0'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to calculate the **total sum** value of products for each `CategoryName`, then get the category where the total sum is the greatest, and **display this sum**.

To find the maximum total price, first you need to find the total price for each category.

You can do it either by using a combination of collectors `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingDouble` as a downstream, or with `Collectors.toMap` by providing a *merge function* as a third argument of this collector.

And then create a stream over the values of the intermediate map and retrieve the maximum.

---

If you need both maximum total price and a name of category, then need to create a stream over the entry set and peek the entry with maximum value providing `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` as comparator.

```
    private static Map.Entry<String, Double> getMaxByCategoryName(List<ProductCategories> categoryList) {
        return categoryList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductCategories::getCategoryName,
                        ProductCategories::getPrice,
                        Double::sum))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .orElse(Map.entry("no data evalable", 0d));
    }
```

Comment: How can I add the name of the category to which this value belongs?

Answer (score 1):

First, the name of your method is somewhat misleading. You should think about it and change it to something more meaningful than `multiValueMap`.

You can create the sums for the individual categories by simply applying a downstream collector like `Collectors.summingDouble`:

```
private static Map<String, Double> multiValueMap(List<ProductCategories> categoryList) {
    return categoryList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductCategories::getCategoryName,
                    Collectors.summingDouble(ProductCategories::getPrice)));
}
```